# Man's indication OR invasion of many planets?

Tags: word-choice

I am confused between 2 choices in the following questions:

***As we are living in the age of technology, man's ............. of many planets is remarkable.***

***a) invention***

***b) indication***

***c) invasion***

***d) inspiration***

In the answers it is ***c) invasion***, but unless we are in 2439 or something, shouldn't it be ***b) indication*** or there is actually something wrong with the sentence itself ?

Comment: As a native speaker, I'm of the opinion that question is just *awful*. None of those choices are a good fit, and the sentence itself is just awkward overall. I would expect to see something like "discovery" or "observation" listed as a choice. Was this a homework question?

Comment: @MarkBeadles I agree, i just had to find the best fit (which seemed ***indication*** to me), regarding that this is an exam, the kind of the exam that your admission to your university of choice would depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them produce a meaning that makes sense. **Indication**, however, seems to be wrong in syntax as well as meaning.

#### Man's indication of many planets

This has both nonsense meaning and nonsense syntax. 
Man is an indication of many planets, or even Man's an indication of many planets would be correct syntax. Man's indication that many planets... could also be correct syntax for that part of the sentence, but then you run into verb agreement problems.

The others have a meaning that is either currently false, or nonsense, but use correct syntax:

#### Man's invasion of many planets

We haven't done that, but it's a thing that could happen, and the syntax is correct.

#### Man's invention of many planets

We also haven't done that for a real planet, but one could certainly invent a planet, and in fact, many authors have. This doesn't, however, match the context of "As we are living in the age of technology, ...is remarkable"

#### Man's inspiration of many planets

I haven't inspired any planets, and planets are not conscious beings, so this is probably the one with the most nonsense meaning, but the syntax is correct.

Perhaps you could clarify the question stem?  If I was looking for the most WRONG answer, I'd choose indication.

Comment: Inspiration has an additional definition ([number 6](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inspiration?s=t)), but it isn't really any more sensible.

Comment: @KamilDrakari yes, of course! Considering the age we live in it is *quite* remarkable that we're still breathing in planets!

Answer (score 1):

I think the word "invasion" is the best candidate here, though I agree it does not seem to fit in the context. Maybe the writer does not use the word to literally mean "the act of using force to enter or take control of another place" but just simply "the act of entering a place (in this case, other planets)" probably by sending machines and vehicles to other planets like Mars?

Comment: But does the word "invasion" have double meanings ? I actually almost thought the same but the fact that the sentence had "many" made me think that the action involved "many planets", which is why i saw that ***indication*** is a better choice. :/

Comment: But an indication is a sign that something exists or true so that doesn't work in this context either. :'( Just think of it as an English test, not a science one. Forget all the facts! Hehe

Comment: NOAD defines _invasion_ as "an unwelcome intrusion into another's domain" while WordNet reads "any entry into an area not previously occupied". Your conjecture is the only one that makes sense to me, although _exploration_ would be a much better word than _invasion_.